# Sum current month value with previous last 5 month value in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with some values. Here I need to make a calculation for Year 2019 only.

```
$array = array(
                "date_2019_12" => 0,
                "date_2019_11" => 0,
                "date_2019_10" => 0,
                "date_2019_09" => 0,
                "date_2019_08" => 0,
                "date_2019_07" => 0,
                "date_2019_06" => 0,
                "date_2019_05" => 0,
                "date_2019_04" => 0,
                "date_2019_03" => 0,
                "date_2019_02" => 0,
                "date_2019_01" => 10,
                "date_2018_12" => 1,
                "date_2018_11" => 2,
                "date_2018_10" => 3,
                "date_2018_09" => 4,
                "date_2018_08" => 5,
                "date_2018_07" => 6,
        );

        krsort($array);
```

From this array, I need to calculate the sum of previous five months & current month starting "date_2019_01".

That means I need final array result like below:

```
"date_2019_01" => 25(10+1+2+3+4+5)
"date_2019_02" => 20(0+10+1+2+3+4)
"date_2019_03" => 16(0+0+10+1+2+3)
"date_2019_04" => 13(0+0+0+10+1+2)
... until "date_2019-12".
```

I have spend many times finding solution but I could not. Can anybody help me?

I have tried following code and somewhere now I am lost.

```
$newArr = array();
        foreach($array as $key => $val) {
            $explode = explode("_", $key);
            $value = (int)$explode[2];
            for($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
                $newArr[$array[$explode[0].'_'.$explode[1].'_'.$value]] = $array[$explode[0].'_'.$explode[1].'_'.$value];
                $value--;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do what you want. It uses a nested loop to iterate over each month and the 5 preceding months, creating a sum for each one from the different date values in the array:

```
$year = 2019;
$sums = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
    $sum = 0;
    for ($j = $i - 5; $j <= $i; $j++) {
        $y = $year;
        $m = $j;
        if ($m <= 0) {
            $m += 12;
            $y -= 1;
        }
        $date = sprintf("date_%4d_%02d", $y, $m);
        $sum += $array[$date];
    }
    $date = sprintf("date_%4d_%02d", $year, $i);
    $sums[$date] = $sum;
}
print_r($sums);
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [date_2019_01] => 25
  [date_2019_02] => 20
  [date_2019_03] => 16
  [date_2019_04] => 13
  [date_2019_05] => 11
  [date_2019_06] => 10
  [date_2019_07] => 0
  [date_2019_08] => 0
  [date_2019_09] => 0
  [date_2019_10] => 0
  [date_2019_11] => 0
  [date_2019_12] => 0 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/BhpAG)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to nest the loops, you can use one loop, array_slice and array_sum.

```
krsort($array);

$year = "2019";
$keys = array_keys($array); //save keys since we use array_values in the loop
foreach(array_values($array) as $k => $v){
    // If the year is found in the key slice out the next six item and sum them
    if(strpos($keys[$k], $year) !== false) $res[$keys[$k]] = array_sum(array_slice($array, $k, 6)); 
}
var_dump($res);
```

https://3v4l.org/LSQRg

Comment: You should adapt your code to show 2018 values as well.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa OP only wanted data for 2019

Comment: As Nick says, OP wants to be able to select year (I believe).

Comment: Fair enough but your code wont work in 2020 because your using magic numbers. Anyway nice solution `array_sum` is fater than `foreach` and better to use.

Comment: @AndreiLupuleasa why wouldn't my code work in 2020? What magic number?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming), because of the `strpos($keys[$k], $year)`  if  `"date_2020_01" => 0` - just saying

Comment: $year is (obviously) a input string that the user inputs in order to get a desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Use: https://3v4l.org/7AYfT

```
        $newArr = array();
        foreach($array as $key => $val) {
            $i=1;
            $newArr[$key] = $val;
            foreach($array as $key2 => $val2){
                if($key>$key2 && $i <= 5){
                    $newArr[$key] += $val2;
                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }

array(18) {
  ["date_2019_12"]=>
  int(0)
  ["date_2019_11"]=>
  int(0)
  ["date_2019_10"]=>
  int(0)
  ["date_2019_09"]=>
  int(0)
  ["date_2019_08"]=>
  int(0)
  ["date_2019_07"]=>
  int(0)
  ["date_2019_06"]=>
  int(10)
  ["date_2019_05"]=>
  int(11)
  ["date_2019_04"]=>
  int(13)
  ["date_2019_03"]=>
  int(16)
  ["date_2019_02"]=>
  int(20)
  ["date_2019_01"]=>
  int(25)
  ["date_2018_12"]=>
  int(21)
  ["date_2018_11"]=>
  int(20)
  ["date_2018_10"]=>
  int(18)
  ["date_2018_09"]=>
  int(15)
  ["date_2018_08"]=>
  int(11)
  ["date_2018_07"]=>
  int(6)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps I have performed.

**Step 1**: Sorting custom format array by keys

```
// sort the array first by date of given format
uksort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    $t1 = strtotime(str_replace(["date_", "_"], ["", "-"], $a) . '-01');
    $t2 = strtotime(str_replace(["date_", "_"], ["", "-"], $b) . '-01');
    return $t1 - $t2;
});
```

**Step 2**: Main logic to given condition with inline documentation

```
$flag   = false;
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if ($key != 'date_2019_01' && !$flag) {
        continue; // check until 'date_2019_01' wont come
    } else {
        $flag   = true; // set the flag and skip above condition
        $curKey = array_search($key, array_keys($array), true); // get integer index of date_2019_01
        if ($key !== false) { // if key exists
            $slice        = array_slice($array, $curKey - 5, 6, true); // from current index last 5(6-5, 7-5,8-5,....) to 6(including current element)
            $result[$key] = array_sum($slice); // sum of there values
        }
    }
}
```

Brief of things I have used to make it clear for understanding of applications of it.

[uksort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php) — Sort an array by keys using a user-defined comparison function
[array_keys](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) — Return all the keys or a subset of the keys of an array
[array_search](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) — Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful
[array_slice](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) — Extract a slice of the array
[array_sum](https://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) — Calculate the sum of values in an array
[str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) — Replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string